# AdventureWorks 2014 Download Issue With File Type

Tags: sql, adventureworks

I am attempting to download AdventureWorks 2014. I downloaded from codeplex, which now exists in my WinZip as a .bak using Notepad as the default program. I unzipped the file, copied over to Program Files...SQLServer...Data. However, I believe the Notepad program will cause an issue when attempting to import the database. I was expecting to see AdventureWorks files ending in .mdf and .ldf. Would I need to change the default program for .bak or .zip? Also, what would I need to change it to to be able to successfully run the AdventureWorks import script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The .bak file is a database backup file.  Once you restore the database through SQL Server, you'll get your .mdf and .ldf files.  Here's how to restore a database backup (your .bak file) for SQL Server 2014.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Thank you. So would I run the Create Database command before the Restore Database command? I am looking it up and seeing it done two different ways.

Comment: If you use the instructions in that link that I posted, you shouldn't need to type any SQL commands.  You can do everything through the Restore Database dialog box.  In step 4 of those instructions, your backup device will be "file".

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.  Yes, you can create your database first, and then restore it, but you don't need to.  When you restore the backup, it'll create your database.

Comment: Just realized that when I went to Restore Database and database did not exist in the drop down. I'm going to attempt to create the database now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't try to select your database from the "database" dropdown.  It won't be there (unless you've already made it before).  Change "Source" to "Device", then click the "browse" button, then select your .bak file.  You can create your database ahead of time, but you don't need to.  It's easier just to restore the .bak file and let that create your database.

Comment: Is it easier to create through the UI or run the SQL command? I'm worried my notepad file does not end in .bak, but not sure if that matters too much. I ask because I opened the file and could not understand anything. I'm not sure if that will translate to a successful database.